# Three-wire Control

Tags: solid-state-devices

Is it true that the three-wire control identifies the number of wires between the contactor and the control push buttons? I have been looking through the entire book, but can't seem to find a concise answer.

Comment: easier to search the web https://www.theautomationstore.com/3-wire-control-start-stop-circuit/

Comment: Carlos, which book?  It could help us understand your context.

Comment: The three-wire pushbutton circuit is a standard relay and contactor control circuit. However the solid-state-device tag you attached to your question seems to imply that you have some other context in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it true that the three-wire control identifies the number of wires between the contactor and the control push buttons? I have been looking through the entire book, but can't seem to find a concise answer.

Yes.  It is literal, and that is probably why the book doesn't have it as a definition.  This could also be applied to many devices other than motors.